# Behaviour of javascript split if separator not contained in string

Tags: javascript

What is the proper behaviour of

```
"test".split("/")
```

Should the result be ["test"] or undefined? I am asking because I get different results for two different javascript engines. Most browsers seem to return ["test"], so I wonder if the deviating behaviour should be considered a bug.

Comment: What browser gives different behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ES5 specification for `String.prototype.split`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.4.14) does not allow for any return result other than an array, so `undefined` is not correct.